# Manage Finder favourites with defaults write or similar?

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, applescript, defaults

I've been unable to find any preferences list file with the locations for the 'Favorites' list shown in the Finder sidebar. No luck from likely candidates `com.apple.finder` and `com.apple.sidebarlists`.

Is there one, such that I can edit this list with `defaults`?

Failing that, is there a way of managing this list via AppleScript?

Answer (score 2):

Some scripts for this:

- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/27814/finder-settings-script
- https://www.jamf.com/jamf-nation/discussions/20218/the-slftool-thread (using repo below, I think)

And there is a relevant github that can manage these preferences as well:
https://github.com/mosen/mysides

[Edit: Seems like, due to a change with sfltool in 10.3, people are using this: https://github.com/robperc/FinderSidebarEditor ]